# Frequency distribution and number of samples

Tags: distributions, frequency

Suppose I have a frequency distribution of some process of `f_n(x)` that is based on `n` samples, with `n < N`. I want to know the frequency distribution `f_N(x)` for `N` samples. The process was in `n` timesteps, and what I want to do is use the same distribution for a larger number of timesteps. The timesteps for both timeseries are the same.

Is it correct to just scale `f_n` by a factor `N/n`, so that I get

> f_N(x) = N/n f_n(x)

What is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Are the timesteps smaller (i.e. faster sampling over an equivalent time period) or are they the same (i.e same sampling rate over a longer period)?

Comment: They're the same. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think you can scale frequency distribution from the smaller sample.  The reasoning is essentially an assumption that the process is stationary (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process).

You could also create confidence intervals for each range bin about the scaled average, but the mean or expected value for each would indeed be simply the scaled version exactly as you describe.

Comment: Why would I want to use confidence intervals on each range bin? Is that to account for quantization effects and to account for sample time variation?

Comment: Just for randomness.  Assuming there is some stationary probability of each sample landing in each bin, then you will have a range based on any finite number of samples.

Comment: If I have a continuous distribution function with a good fit on the data, then I don't have to do that, or do I?